# MenuListener not working

Tags: java, listener, jmenu

I am trying to **create a JMenu with a MenuListener to exit when selected**, but the program is not exiting.

Compiler does not show any error message. Not sure if it is the `e.getsource()` not working or if it is something else.

Thank you in advance.

```
 import java.awt.*;


import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.MenuEvent;
import javax.swing.event.MenuListener;

public class entree implements MenuListener{
    JFrame frame;
    JMenu exit,teach;
    entree(){
        Font font=new Font("SansSerif",Font.BOLD,22);
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon("D:\\Capture_aurora.png");
        JLabel  bg=new JLabel(icon);
        JMenuBar mb=new JMenuBar();

        JMenu teach=new JMenu("Teach");
        JMenu exit =new JMenu("Exit");
        teach.setFont(font);exit.setFont(font);exit.addMenuListener(this);teach.addMenuListener(this);

        mb.add(teach);mb.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());mb.add(exit);


        JButton button1=new JButton("Start");
        button1.setFont(font);
        button1.setBounds(870,820,150,45);

        frame.setJMenuBar(mb);
        frame.add(button1);
        frame.add(bg,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);


        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
    public static void main(String[]args) {new entree();}

    public void menuSelected(MenuEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==exit) {
         System.exit(0);frame.dispose();}// Code supposed to work here, but the program won't exit
        if(e.getSource()==teach) {} 
        }

    public void menuDeselected(MenuEvent e) {

    }
    public void menuCanceled(MenuEvent e) {

    }

    }
```

Comment: shouldn't you have those listeners added to MenuItems, instead of to the Menu itself?

Comment: I think I would just need ActionListener for MenuItems and it wud work fine, ActionListener cant be implemented to JMenus thats why i m using MenuListener.

Comment: don't. you're not supposed to add listeners to the menu, but to the menuitems. the Menu isn't the "clickable" element you want, the MenuItem is

Comment: Perhaps you should take a closer look at [How to use menus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html)

Comment: Yeah,but there would b just two items so I didnt bother adding them in a single menu and isn't MenuListener should be working?

Comment: A menu is generally a container for `JMenuItem`s, which are the units of work grouped by the `JMenu` - typically, they aren't "actionable" items

Comment: @Spots no, that's not how it works

Comment: Well maybe I would just add them in a Menu as Items and set ActionListener to them . Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Spots If you only want those two items, I would consider a `JToolBar` or simply adding buttons to a `JPanel` and placing that at the `NORTH` position of a `BorderLayout`

Answer (score 2):

## Answer to the question

You're shadowing your variables...

```
public class entree implements MenuListener {

    JFrame frame;
    JMenu exit, teach;

    entree() {
        //...
        JMenu teach = new JMenu("Teach");
        JMenu exit = new JMenu("Exit");
```

You're creating local variables in the constructor with the same names as the instance fields you are trying to compare later.  This means that `exit` and `teach` are actually `null` when you try and compare them in the `menuSelected` event handler.

## Suggestions...

Generally speaking, this really isn't how `JMenu`s are suppose to work, they aren't meant to be "actionable" items, they are meant to be containers for like items (implemented as `JMenuItem`s).

I would consider either using a `JToolBar` or `JPanel` with `JButton`s which is added to the `NORTH` position of a `BorderLayout` instead.  From a user's perspective, it would make for a more common and expected user experience - IMHO